# Targeted Push Notification

Tags: .net, azure, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I'm currently doing a location-based project.

I use sql management studio to create and maintain the database.
I use Visual studio 2015 to create the website.
I use Bing Maps for retrieving coordinates based on the dropped pin and store the coordinates in my local DB.
Windows phone is used for the mobile app(receiving notification&location).
And Finally I use Azure Mobile Service to push notification to the phone.

Here's the scenario of my project:

1. Website will drop a pin on bing maps, and users fill the additional textboxes.
2. I have a sql query to sort the users that is within the location of the dropped pin on bing maps. The idea is to push these additional info and pinpoint the location on the mobile app(bing map is used in the app). The submit button will then store the coordinates(Longitude&Latitude) with the additional info into the DB.

Here's what is already done:
1. Website with bingmaps, a panel that displays users within the dropped pin, text boxes for additional info, and finally the submit button.
2. WP app that has bing map inside.
3. Azure mobile service (I can send notifications through the azure portal).

The Problem:

I only want to send the coordinates and additional info based on the user_id that is within radius of the dropped pin on the website.
As far as I know from reading on various web, that Azure push notifications can only be sent to ALL that is on the mobile service. And I would only like to send the push notification ONLY to those within the area based on the user_id from the website.

Is there any reference I can use to send TARGETED notifications based on the user id that I want?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out Azure Mobile engagement to send notifications to targeted subset of clients
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/mobile-engagement-user-interface-reach-criterion/